# What is the group $SO^*(12)$?

Tags: reference-request, notation, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Table 5 of [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6523.pdf) refers to a group $SO^\star(12)$ but gives no reference for the name. Does anybody have a reference on it?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, I've seen $SO^\ast(4n)$ used to denote the "other" $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ quotient of $Spin(4n)$.  Specially, the center $Z(Spin(4n))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  The unique outer automorphism of $Spin(4n)$ (for $n\neq 2$) interchanges $(1,0)$ with $(0,1)$, so there are two isomorphism classes of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ quotients of $Spin(4n)$.  One is $SO(4n)$, and the other is $SO^\ast(4n)$.  (When $n=2$, there are extra outer automorphisms.  In this case, $SO(8)$ is actually isomorphic to $SO^\ast(8)$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $\textrm{SO}^*(2 \ell)$ sometimes denotes the (semisimple, real, connected) subgroup of matrices in $\textrm{SO}(2 \ell, \Bbb C)$ that preserve a skew-Hermitian form on the standard representation, $\Bbb C^{2\ell}$. One can always choose a (complex) basis $(z_1, \ldots, z_{2 \ell})$ with respect to which the form is

$$-z_1 \overline w_{\ell + 1} + z_{\ell + 1} \overline w_1 - \cdots - z_\ell \overline w_{2\ell} + z_{2\ell} \overline w_{\ell} ,$$

and as a matrix group, written with respect to such a basis, $\textrm{SO}^*(2\ell)$ comprises exactly the $2\ell \times 2 \ell$ block matrices

$$\pmatrix{A & B\\-\bar{B}&-\bar{A}}$$

for which $A$ is a skew complex matrix and $B$ is a Hermitian complex matrix.

These groups are respectively real forms of $D_{\ell} = \mathrm{SO}(2\ell, \Bbb C)$ and so have (real) dimension $\ell (2 \ell - 1)$; their behavior depends mildly on the parity of $\ell$. The groups with $\ell \leq 4$ are isogenous to more familiar groups, and in that sense the smallest "new" group in this family is $\mathrm{SO}^*(10)$.
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\hline
\mathfrak{so}^*(2) &\cong &\mathfrak{u}(1) \cong \mathfrak{so}(2) \\
\mathfrak{so}^*(4) &\cong &\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(1, 1) \cong \mathfrak{so}(3) \oplus \mathfrak{so}(1, 2)\\
\mathfrak{so}^*(6) &\cong &\mathfrak{su}(1, 3)\\
\mathfrak{so}^*(8) &\cong &\mathfrak{so}(2, 6)\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

For more, see, e.g., Helgason's *Differential Geometry and Symmetric Spaces*, $\S$IX.4, which does not give this group a descriptive name. Harvey's *Spinors and Calibrations*, $\S$1, calls this group the **skew-unitary group** and denotes it by the (I think, unusual) notation $\textrm{SK}(\ell, \mathbb H)$. See also [Quaternionic Orthogonal Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group#O%E2%88%97(2n)_=_O(n,_H)-_quaternionic_orthogonal_group).

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/star-groups-su-n.902371/).
"The star indicates the *projective* group, that is the factor group of its center $\epsilon_n\cdot $ with n-th roots of unity $\epsilon_n$."

The orthogonal group is $SO(n)$, and the star group is $SO^*(n)$.